# Is it possible to external reference a path once?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I've got two workbooks, where Workbook A pulls out different cells from different worksheets of Workbook B and adds them altogether. Problem is, it does this so much that it can end up causing a formula in excess of the 8000+ characters because of the filepath.

Is there a formula or method that would help shorten this? Perhaps a way where you only refer to the file path once and then every cell reference inside the formula knows it's to that same file path? The process of constantly repeating the filepath just to get the Worksheet & Cell Reference is what causes the current simple addition formula to balloon. I cannot use a SUM function it would capture other data not intended.

Comment: what is your formula/layout? Is VBA possible, if only to open n close the sheets needed?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a criteria for what values you would want to sum, you can use the SUMIF/S function to add these values considering your criteria.

Ex.: `=SUMIF('D:\test\[test_file.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1:A200,">="&3,'D:\test\[test_file.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1:A200)`

will add values equal to or more than 3 in range A1:A200 of Sheet1 in test_file.xlsx in D:\test\ directory.

Another method is typing in the source workbook directory in a cell and making use of an INDIRECT function to do your addition.

Ex.: If you enter `'D:\test\[test_file.xlsx]Sheet1'!` as text in cell B1, you can add values of A2, A5 and A7 by typing in `=sum(indirect(B1&"A2"),indirect(B1&"A5"),indirect(B1&"A7"))` thus significantly reducing character length.

You can as well try to reference all relevant cells of the source workbook to another sheet in the destination workbook and make your addition from that "helper" sheet.

I'd prefer the SUMIF/S option and having a reliable criteria to work with.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to have worked out for me is using SUMPRODUCT. It has cut down on the formula length considerably. As there is a standard criteria of which I wanted to multiply across different worksheets, Array one refers looks for matching criteria from the first worksheet and then uses Array 2 for each worksheet.